# How to auto create Sheet Name based in names in column A in Sheet1 in google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm still learning GoogleApp scripting by myself. Can anyone guide me in the right direction how to edit the below script in such a way that instead of naming the new sheet as per the current date, it takes the names from the column A of Sheet1 and then rename it.

Note that i keep on updating column A with new name in new cells down the column off an on.

Thank you for your help in advance!

This is the script I have which works for dates only:

```
function onOpen() {
var menu = [{name: "Add", functionName: "newSheet"}];
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Sheet", menu);
}

function newSheet() {
var sheetName = formatDate();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var templateSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
ss.insertSheet(sheetName, ss.getSheets().length, {template: templateSheet});
}

function formatDate() {
var month, day, d = new Date();
month = ('0'+(d.getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
day = ('0'+d.getUTCDate()).slice(-2);
return d.getUTCFullYear()+'-'+month+'-'+day;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below gets all the values in col A from A2:A, filters them to ignore blank cells in the data and then checks if the sheets already exist if they already exist nothing happens. If the sheets don't exist it copies the template sheet, renames it and puts it at the end of the sheet tabs.

```
function onOpen() {
    var menu = [{
            name : "Add",
            functionName : "newSheet"
        }
    ];
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Sheet", menu);
}

function newSheet() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var templateSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
        var getNames = sheet1.getRange("A2:A").getValues().filter(String).toString().split(",");

    for (var i = 0; i < getNames.length; i++) {
        var copy = ss.getSheetByName(getNames[i]);
        if (copy) {
            Logger.log("Sheet already exists");
        } else {
            templateSheet.copyTo(ss).setName(getNames[i]);
            ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(getNames[i]));
            ss.moveActiveSheet(ss.getNumSheets());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi James! Thank you very much! It did exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works out for you.

```
function onOpen() {
  var menu = [{name: "Add", functionName: "newSheet"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Sheet", menu);
}

function newSheet()
{
  var sp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetnameobj = sp.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  //You can place a for loop here, if you want to create multiple sheets
  var newsheetname = sheetnameobj.getRange("A2").getValue();//Get Name of Your New Sheet From Column A of Sheet1

  sp.insertSheet(newsheetname);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Parag for your solution! Short and simple. Though it is taking the data from the cell A2 only, whereas what i asked for is since i keep on updating the cells of column A down the column, it script should keep that in mind. But anyway, thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of help, I got that you want to get multiple values from Column A. It's not that hard to do, I gave you a direction to work in